# How To Store DialogFlow all the Parameter Value On Realtime Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, google-home, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am making a action for Google Home. It's about restaurant booking so I have to take some information from users like:

1. How many guests do you want to book the table for?
2. For which date?
3. For which time?

Then I have to store it on Firebase real time database. For the `guests` parameter it is writing the value to the database **but the date and time parameters are not showing on database**.

**what will be code for storing both time and date with guests in database?**

```js
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 
 //initialize db connection
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp();
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }
 
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}
  function createBooking(agent) {
      
    let guests = agent.parameters.guests;
    let time = new Date(agent.parameters.time);
    let date = new Date(agent.parameters.date);
    let bookingDate = new Date(date);
    bookingDate.setHours(time.getHours());
    bookingDate.setMinutes(time.getMinutes());
    let now = new Date();
      const guestsParam = agent.parameters.guests;
     
      if (guests < 1){
        agent.add('You need to reserve a table for at least one person. Please try again!');
    } else if (bookingDate < now){
        agent.add(`You can't make a reservation in the past. Please try again!`);
    } else if (bookingDate.getFullYear() > now.getFullYear()) {
        agent.add(`You can't make a reservation for ${bookingDate.getFullYear()} yet. Please choose a date in ${now.getFullYear()}.`);
    } else {
        let timezone = parseInt(agent.parameters.time.toString().slice(19,22));
        bookingDate.setHours(bookingDate.getHours() + timezone);
        agent.add(`You have successfully booked a table for ${guests} guests on ${bookingDate.toString().slice(0,21)}`);
        agent.add('See you at the restaurant!');
    }
     return admin.database().ref('/guests').push({guests: guests}).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('database write successful: ' + snapshot.ref.toString());
  });
  
        
 }
    
 
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('restaurant.booking.create', createBooking);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simple answer is that you don't see them in the database because you don't put them there.

The line

```
admin.database().ref('/guests').push({guests: guests})
```

Just stores a document with the guests. You don't do anything with `bookingDate`.

Comment: How Do i store my three parameter in database for guests it is storing what will be code for storing time and sate with guests?@Prisoner

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If this is a problem with your code, please update the original question and explain what is happening.

Comment: It looks like you've asked the new question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54267643/1405634. If this answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is appreciated.